# Problem Sorting With Multiple SPGridViews

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spgridview

I am using an [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) control with an ObjectDataSource control in a SharePoint 2010 solution. The SPGridview allows me to sort and page through a list items OK, but I have noticed a problem when two SPGridView controls are placed on the same page.  When I sort the lower SPGridView control by clicking on a column's header link, the sort operation is successful. However when I click on the sort options available through the ECB menu on the lower SPGridView's column header, the sort is applied to the upper SPGridView control instead.

Can anyone offer a fix or guidance on how to resolve this?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a thread on MSDN explaining the bug and a resolution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/af6167a3-21f2-4bb2-94a9-5c22e1aad34d

Here is another blog post describing it as well - http://sharethefrustration.blogspot.com/2010/02/spgridview-webpart-with-multiple-filter.html

Comment: Brian, apologies for the delay in accepting this as an answer.  I have posted my solution, which was based on the links you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the links provided by [brian brinley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240250/brian-brinley), I came up with this slightly more generic solution:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.HeaderRow != null)
    {
        foreach (WebControl control in this.HeaderRow.Controls)
        {                    
            UpdateTemplateClientID(control);
        }      
    }

    base.OnPreRender(e);
}

private void UpdateTemplateClientID(Control control)
{
    if (control is Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu)
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu menuControl = control as Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Menu;
        string jsFunctionCall = menuControl.ClientOnClickPreMenuOpen;
        menuControl.ClientOnClickPreMenuOpen = jsFunctionCall.Replace("%TEMPLATECLIENTID%", this.ClientID + "_SPGridViewFilterMenuTemplate");
    }
    else if (control.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (WebControl c in control.Controls)
        {
            UpdateTemplateClientID(c);
        }
    }
}
```